# What happens to the previous "new" operator?

Tags: c#

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_dt);
```

I have a question about the `new` keyword. I have a DispatcherTimer which I set to an interval. Let’s say the user wants to change the interval.

```
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
```

So, what happens to the very first `new TimeSpan`? Is it still there? Or does the new one override the previous? I don’t think it does.

And if I want to change the interval, is the `new` keyword the only way to declare a new TimeSpan? I am asking this, since I’m not sure whether it’s actually okay or even right to declare a new TimeSpan every time the value changes.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you may be interested in the `TimeSpan.FromXXX` methods - they can help to make your code clearer.  In this instance: `dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)`

Comment: this is actually what i was looking for, i mean okey apparently  it´s not a big deal to declare a new TimeSpan, but it just didn´t looked right for me todo that every time the Value changes. Thanks i will keep this in mind.

Comment: The `TimeSpan.FromXXX` methods are just helper methods that internally do `new TimeSpan` anyway, so the question is still the same either way.

Comment: Note that using a backtick instead of an apostrophe (a) is poor English punctuation practice, and (b) may lead to weird formatting effects on this website.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, coming from a C++ background? Because if so, keep in mind that `new` is mostly an artifact of the language, and that C# is automatically garbage collected.

Comment: @Raiho Why dt_dt in Event Handler argument? Is that a variable or something else?

Comment: @NicHartley nope not at all. thx for the info though

Comment: @ChetanMehra       no reason just the name of the Handler  private void dt_dt(object sender, EventArgs e){}   didnt rly thought much about the name  when i posted this question (is just an example)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have class (`DispatcherTimer`) which has field of type `TimeSpan`, and `TimeSpan` is a struct.

Since it's a struct - it's "embedded" into instance of `DispatcherTimer`. So instance of `DispatcherTimer` looks in memory like this:

```
<various metadata>...<contents of timespan>...
```

If it were class (reference type), it would look like this:

```
<various metadata>...<reference to timespan>...
```

When you do

```
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
```

Instance of `TimeSpan` is allocated (on stack in this case) and copied to the memory region of `DispatcherTimer` instance allocated for `Interval`, overwriting what was there before.

So we had

```
<various metadata>...<contents of timespan 1>
```

and now we have

```
<various metadata>...<contents of timespan 2>
```

That means old interval timespan is simply overwritten, it will not be collected by garbage collector because there is just nothing to collect (contrary to what accepted answer claims).

For that reason doing that in a tight loop is also not a problem (though of course there is no reason to). Consider this code:

```
class ClassWithRefField {
    public TestClass Field;
}

class ClassWithStructField {
    public TestStruct Field;
}

class TestClass {
    public TestClass(int payload) {
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public int Payload;
}

struct TestStruct {
    public TestStruct(int payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public int Payload;
}
```

Then if you do:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var f = new ClassWithRefField();
    while (true) {
        f.Field = new TestClass(1);
    }            
}
```

And observe process memory even in process explorer in windows - you will see that memory constantly grows and drops. That's instances of `TestClass` are created on heap and collected by garbage collector.

However if you do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var f = new ClassWithStructField();
    while (true) {
        f.Field = new TestStruct(1);
    }            
}
```

Memory in process explorer will stay absolutely constant, because the same region of memory is constantly overwritten, so there is nothing to collect. This loop can run forever.

And yes - it's ok to do it the way you are doing.

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed explanation i understand now how it actually works, good to know that it actually constantly overwrites.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are multiple things to consider here. Yes, it does create a second instance of the `TimeSpan` struct. Since the first one isn't referenced anywhere, it will go out of scope and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector. No harm done.

*If* `TimeSpan` would have been a class, you probably change one of the properties, but it is a struct, and structs are usually immutable, meaning you can't change their value. (This is due to multiple reasons, I would suggest to read up on that)

So the only option you have here is to create a new `TimeSpan` struct instance. That is no problem if you don't do it in a tight loop (creating a low of new instances in a very short time, consuming lots of memory).